# Text Rotation HTML 5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I would like to add some text to the canvas and rotate the text in a circle like a pinwheel.

How would you do this.  I just want a continuous loop where the text never stops spinning.

```
function showCircularNameRotating(string, startAngle, endAngle){
//context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
circle = {
    x: canvas.width/2,
    y: canvas.height/2,
    radius: 200
};

var radius = circle.radius,
    angleDecrement = (startAngle - endAngle)/string.length-1),
    angle = parseFloat(startAngle),
    index = 0,
    character;

context.save();
while(index <string.length){
character = stringcharAt(index);
context.save();
context.beginPath();
context.translate(circle.x + Math.cos(angle) * radius,
                  circle.y - Math.sin(angle) * radius);
context.rotate(math.PI/2 - angle);

context.fillText(charater, 0,0);
context.strokeText(character,0,0);
angle -= angleDecrement;
index++;
context.restore();
}
context.restore();

}

drawCircularText("Clockwise", Math.PI*2, Math.PI/8);
```

Comment: You've posted a huge chunk of code here.
Can you tell us what went wrong with the code you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple code to rotate text could look like this - adopt as needed:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    w = canvas.width,
    h = canvas.height,
    cx = w * 0.5,                  // center of canvas
    cy = h * 0.5,
    angleStep = 0.1,
    txt = 'PINWHEEL TEXT';

ctx.font = 'bold 30px sans-serif'; // set font
ctx.textAlign = 'center';          // align text in center
ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';

(function rotate() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);     // clear canvas
    ctx.translate(cx, cy);         // translate to center of rotation
    ctx.rotate(angleStep);         // rotate (accumulative)
    ctx.translate(-cx, -cy);       // translate back
    ctx.fillText(txt, cx, cy);     // draw text at rotated center

    requestAnimationFrame(rotate); // loop
})();
```

### [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/PL284/)

**Update**

Generic function for it (keep canvas and context outside):

```
function rotateText(ctx, txt, font, angleStep, cx, cy) {

    var w = ctx.canvas.width,
        h = ctx.canvas.height;

    cx = cx || w * 0.5;                // defaults to center if cx/cy isn't given
    cy = cy || h * 0.5;

    ctx.font = font;
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';

    (function rotate() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);     // clear canvas
        ctx.translate(cx, cy);         // translate to center of rotation
        ctx.rotate(angleStep);         // rotate (accumulative)
        ctx.translate(-cx, -cy);       // translate back
        ctx.fillText(txt, cx, cy);     // draw text at rotated center

        requestAnimationFrame(rotate); // loop
    })();
}
```

Now just call:

```
rotateText(ctx, 'MyText', '32px myfont', 0.1);
```

or

```
rotateText(ctx, 'MyText', '32px myfont', 0.1, centerX, centerY);
```

Comment: Is it possible to put this code in another function?

Comment: @user3380698 certainly, just wrap most of it inside a call which allow you to set for example steps. Canvas and context does not need to be inside it either. I updated answer with an example (untested).

Comment: Cool Now taking your animation you provided how could you take text and wrap it around a circle and then animate it to move around a circle.  Im stumped how to do this

Comment: @user3380698 Here is one solution :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22212150/html5-canvas-text-animating-around-circle/22212590#22212590