# HTML 5 draw curved text on a image

Tags: html, svg, html5-canvas

How we can draw a curved text on a image in a particular position like below.
[image]

Comment: One approach for canvas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22212150/html5-canvas-text-animating-around-circle/22212590#22212590

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `<textPath>` SVG elements to draw text on a path. It can be a little bit fiddly, but I'll walk you through it.

First you need to create a `<defs>` section containing the paths you want your text to follow. It would make things easier if you could just use a `<circle>` element, but that won't work; it has to be a `<path>` element. Fortunately, SVG's path drawing does support [circular arcs](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands), so there's no need to faff about with Bézier curves.

Here I'm defining two semicircular arcs centred on (0,0) with a radius of 120; `cp1` goes clockwise over the top, and `cp2` goes anticlockwise around the bottom:

```
  <defs>
    <path id="cp1" d="M-120 0A120 120 0 0 1 120 0" fill="none" stroke="red" />
    <path id="cp2" d="M-120 0A120 120 0 0 0 120 0" fill="none" stroke="red" />
  </defs>
```

The actual drawing part of the SVG is wrapped in a `<g>` element to move the origin to the centre of the SVG (which has dimensions of 300×300 in this case):

```
  <g transform="translate(150,150)">
```

Now create a `<text>` element with the required appearance attributes, and put the `<textPath>` elements inside it. Use `text-anchor="middle"` to keep the text centrally justified, and set the `startOffset` attribute to the distance along the path where you want the text to be anchored. In this case, the offset is equal to one quarter of the circumference of a circle with diameter 120, which is 2 × π × 120 / 4, or 188.5. The `dominant-baseline` attribute indicates how the text is aligned to the curve; a setting of `middle` means that the centre line of the text is aligned to the path, so we can use the same radius for the upper and lower curves. (In some cases this can make the text look a bit squished. You can fix this by setting the `letter-spacing` attribute.)

```
    <text font-size="36" font-family="Courier New" font-weight="bold" fill="white">
      <textPath xlink:href="#cp1" startOffset="188.5" text-anchor="middle"
                dominant-baseline="central">Smooth Roast</textPath>
      <textPath xlink:href="#cp2" startOffset="188.5" text-anchor="middle"
                dominant-baseline="central">Coffee Company</textPath>
    </text>
```

The horizontal text in the middle of the logo can be done in the same way, but using ordinary `<tspan>` elements instead of `<textPath>` elements:

```
    <text font-size="12" font-family="Arial" font-weight="bold" fill="#c97">
      <tspan x="-120" y="0" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">SINCE</tspan>
      <tspan x="120" y="0" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">1981</tspan>
    </text>
```

And here's the finished result:

```html
<svg width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <path id="cp1" d="M-120 0A120 120 0 0 1 120 0" fill="none" stroke="red" />
    <path id="cp2" d="M-120 0A120 120 0 0 0 120 0" fill="none" stroke="red" />
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(150,150)">
    <!-- Circular background: -->
    <circle x="0" y="0" r="150" fill="#820" stroke="none" />
    <circle x="0" y="0" r="145" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="4" />
    <circle x="0" y="0" r="98" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" />
    <!-- This is supposed to look like a coffee cup: -->
    <rect x="-45" y="-40" width="80" height="80" fill="white" stroke="none" />
    <rect x="-45" y="30" width="80" height="20" rx="10" ry="10" fill="white" stroke="none" />
    <ellipse cx="45" cy="0" rx="15" ry="20" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="8" />
    <!-- Text manipulation starts here: -->
    <text font-size="36" font-family="Courier New" font-weight="bold" fill="white">
      <textPath xlink:href="#cp1" startOffset="188.5" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">Smooth Roast</textPath>
      <textPath xlink:href="#cp2" startOffset="188.5" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">Coffee Company</textPath>
    </text>
    <text font-size="12" font-family="Arial" font-weight="bold" fill="#c97">
      <tspan x="-120" y="0" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">SINCE</tspan>
      <tspan x="120" y="0" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">1981</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: +1 Yep, SVG's built in textPath does this task well. Canvas can do text on paths also, but you must manually calculate angles & letter widths.

Comment: I notice you used _xlink:href_, but you did not use `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` ... does the browser understand _xlink:href_ without the namespace declared?

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd Good point. I certainly didn't intend to leave it out, although the browser seems happy enough without it. I'll edit my answer anyway

Comment: I noticed that also ... I am thinking about posting a question about if it is really needed and why ...